# Is there a C++11/14 alternative to __attribute__((packed))

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, c++14

C++11 introduced a concept of standardized attribute syntax. I couldn't find the list of all supported attributes. Is there a C++11 attribute alternative to `__attribute__((packed))`?

e.g.

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) Pack {
   uint8_t field1;
   uint8_t field2;
};
```

Comment: [Something wrong with documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes)?

Comment: C++ standard attributes don't change semantics, unlike `packed`.

Comment: I was under the impression, that it wasn't the full list. Thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The attributes the standard currently defines are:

- `[[noreturn]]`;
- `[[carries_dependency]]`;
- `[[deprecated]]`/`[[deprecated(reason)]]`;

Everything else is implementation-defined.

Comment: @YSC cppreference is a...reference for C++: much of the text is already taken from the standard, though with less formality. [There you have it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

Comment: cppreference is a wiki; by spec I meant the official C++ normalization documents. If you have any idea in which section I can find the C++11 attributes' definitions ...

Comment: @YSC It's under §7.6.{3, 4, 5}, [decl.attr.*]. I won't include it in the answer as such formality is not requested and needed: cppreference is definitely enough, and you'll find its text very close to the normative one. Of course, if it's fyi, it's another thing.

Comment: Fwiw i dont think this is unfortunate, packed structs are often a hack. If you need the struct layout to be portable you can use alignas to increase alignment of some members to a cross platform minimum, rather than risk unaligned load